# Calling a class defined function from a DLL file C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I've built an example project from the Amazon IoT Device SDK which is the PubSub Sample project from the examples folder.

I've had to output the project as a DLL file so that the sample can be used in RAD studio, which I have been able to build successfully. Using the tutorials from generating a DLL, I've added in the  __declspec(dllexport) line to the function definitions in the class.

**PubSub.hpp file**

```
#ifdef PUBSNUB_EXPORTS
#define PUBSNUB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PUBSNUB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "mqtt/Client.hpp"
#include "NetworkConnection.hpp"


namespace awsiotsdk {
    namespace samples {
        class PubSub {
        protected:
            std::shared_ptr<NetworkConnection> p_network_connection_;
            std::shared_ptr<mqtt::ConnectPacket> p_connect_packet_;
            std::atomic_int cur_pending_messages_;
            std::atomic_int total_published_messages_;
            std::shared_ptr<MqttClient> p_iot_client_;

            __declspec(dllexport) ResponseCode RunPublish(int msg_count);
            __declspec(dllexport) ResponseCode SubscribeCallback(util::String topic_name,
                                           util::String payload,
                                           std::shared_ptr<mqtt::SubscriptionHandlerContextData> p_app_handler_data);
            __declspec(dllexport) ResponseCode DisconnectCallback(util::String topic_name,
                                            std::shared_ptr<DisconnectCallbackContextData> p_app_handler_data);
            __declspec(dllexport) ResponseCode ReconnectCallback(util::String client_id,
                                           std::shared_ptr<ReconnectCallbackContextData> p_app_handler_data,
                                           ResponseCode reconnect_result);
            __declspec(dllexport) ResponseCode ResubscribeCallback(util::String client_id,
                                             std::shared_ptr<ResubscribeCallbackContextData> p_app_handler_data,
                                             ResponseCode resubscribe_result);
            __declspec(dllexport) ResponseCode Subscribe();
            __declspec(dllexport) ResponseCode Unsubscribe();
            __declspec(dllexport) ResponseCode InitializeTLS();

        public:
            __declspec(dllexport) ResponseCode RunSample();
        };
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on not knowing how to call the RunSample() in an example Console project as an example to make sure that my DLL file is working properly. I've tried calling the function directly but it's saying it's undefined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PubSub.hpp"

int main()
{
    RunSample();
}
```

Comment: You can't call memberfunctions without an object, but that's basic C++ knowledge.  Also, there are namespaces. Further, you probably need to export the class, not the individual methods of that class.

Comment: So for this particular class, would I put  __declspec(dllexport) in front of class PubSub

Comment: I don't remember (it's been some time), either before or in the middle. You should be able to find examples easily though.

Comment: need `PUBSNUB_API` instead `__declspec(dllexport)` - because for your dll this must be `__declspec(dllexport)` and for caller - `__declspec(dllimport)`. and of course first you need create instance of class - before call member function on it.

Comment: @RbMn ok I've replaced the __declspec(dllexport) with PUBSNUB_API in front of the method definitions but do I put PUBSNUB_API in front of "class PubSub"?

Comment: The class defined in the DLL has to be exported using [__declspec(dllexport)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=vs-2019).
In the file that you're going to use the file, import the class using [__declspec(dllimport)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-into-an-application-using-declspec-dllimport?view=vs-2019).
I suggest you could refer to the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019